# Raphaël Object: Simulate click

Tags: javascript, dom-events, raphael

It it possible to simulate an click on an Raphaël object?
I tried already

```
object.click();  // Error: click is not a function

// or

object.dispatchEvent('click'); // Error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMEventTarget.dispatchEvent]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the DOM node using Element.node as described in the docs. You can then trigger events on the node as you would with any other DOM element

http://jsfiddle.net/UFZXP/

http://lifescaler.com/2008/04/simulating-mouse-clicks-in-javascript/